# How to test custom controller extension?

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

I went through the traiblazer testing module and read a lot online, but to no anvil so far.

**Situation**
I have created a VisualForcePage and an extension class for a standard controller (both see below).

**Challenge**
While not working perfectly, I am ready to deploy. But as you all know I have to pass the testing requirements before. Where I am really struggling, as first add.Fields is not really testable, then all the forumla fields that I am using in my extension do evaluate to null, while testing. Not quite sure what to do about that.

**Extension**

```
public class ExtensionCreatorController {

private final Request__c requ;
public integer result{get;set;}
public double totalMonths{get;set;}
public double initialCommission{get;set;}
public double newLandlordFee{get;set;}
public double newTenantFee{get;set;}
public double newNetLandlordFee{get;set;}
public double newNetTenantFee{get;set;}
public double newTotalRentDuration{get;set;}

/* Constructor */
public ExtensionCreatorController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) stdController.addFields(new List<String>{ 'Opportunity__c'
         ,'Landlord__c'
         ,'Billing_Address__c'
         ,'Billing_Address_c__c'
         ,'Booker_Contact__c'
         ,'ServiceFeeLandlord__c'
         ,'TotalRent__c'
         ,'MonthlyRent__c'
         ,'Tenant_Fee_Type__c'
         ,'Apartment_Country__c'
         ,'TotalRentalTime__c'
         ,'Apartment__c'
         ,'Landlord_Contact__c'
         ,'ON_InvoiceLand__c'
         ,'ON_InvoiceTen__c'
         ,'ON_SubscriptionLand__c'
         ,'ON_SubscriptionTen__c'
         ,'Tenant__c'
         ,'Tenant_Contact__c'});

    this.requ = (Request__c)stdController.getRecord();
}

/* Calculate Intermediate Results */    
public void calculation() {
    result = requ.Moveindate__c.daysBetween(requ.Moveoutdate__c);
    newTotalRentDuration = result + requ.TotalRentalTime__c;
    initialCommission = requ.ServiceFeeLandlord__c/requ.TotalRent__c;

    if (newTotalRentDuration < 366) {
        totalMonths = totalMonths(requ.MoveIndate__c,requ.MoveOutdate__c);
    } else {
        /* ToDo this is only relevant where the rental cap is met calc is a bit dirty 
        as of right now and should actually include the basic request duration in case of chain extensions*/
        totalMonths = math.ceil((365 - requ.TotalRentalTime__c)/30);
    }

    newLandlordFee = initialCommission * totalMonths * requ.MonthlyRent__c;

    if ((requ.Apartment_Country__c == 'Germany') || (requ.Apartment_Country__c == 'Deutschland')) {
        newNetLandlordFee = newLandlordFee/1.19; 
    } 
    else newNetLandlordFee = newLandlordFee;

    newTenantFee = calcTenantFee(totalMonths);
    if ((requ.Apartment_Country__c == 'Germany') || (requ.Apartment_Country__c == 'Deutschland')) {
        newNetTenantFee = newTenantFee/1.19; 
    } 
    else newNetTenantFee = newTenantFee;            
}

/* Insert new Request Record*/
/* ToDo enable redirect: System.PageReference */
public void InsertClone() {
    requ.Extension_of__c = requ.id;
    requ.id = null;
    requ.BookingID__c = requ.name;
    requ.name = 'EX-'+requ.name;
    requ.BookingDateBackEnd__c = Date.today();
    requ.TotalchargetoHomelikeTenant__c = 0;
    requ.TotalpayouttoLandlord__c = 0;
    requ.ServiceFeeLandlord__c = newLandlordFee;
    requ.Net_ServiceFeeLandlord__c = newNetLandlordFee;
    requ.ServiceFeeTenant__c = newTenantFee;
    requ.Net_ServiceFeeTenant__c = newNetTenantFee;
    requ.Status__c = 'Finished';
    insert requ;
    /* return new ApexPages.StandardController(requ).view(); */
}   


/* Helper Methods followig */
public double calcTenantFee(double totalMonths) {
    double result = 0.00;
    /* some logic here */
    return result;  
}

public double totalMonths(Date moveIn, Date moveOut) {
    Integer monthFromYears = (moveOut.year() - moveIn.year())*12;
    Integer monthsInYear = (moveOut.month() - moveIn.month() - 1);
    Double brokenStartMonth = 1.00*(daysInMonth(moveIn) - moveIn.day() + 1)/daysInMonth(moveIn);
    Double brokenEndMonth = 1.00*moveOut.day()/daysInMonth(moveOut);
    return monthFromYears + monthsInYear + brokenStartMonth + brokenEndMonth;
}

public Integer daysInMonth(Date inputDate) {
    Set<Integer> days_31 = new Set<Integer>{1,3,5,7,8,10,12};
    Set<Integer> days_30 = new Set<Integer>{4,6,9,11};
    Set<Integer> days_28 = new Set<Integer>{2};
    Integer numDays;

    if (days_31.contains(inputDate.month())) numDays = 31;
    if (days_30.contains(inputDate.month())) numDays = 30;
    if (days_28.contains(inputDate.month())) {if (math.mod(inputDate.year(),4) == 0) numDays = 29; else numDays = 28;}
    return numDays;
}
```

}

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Request__c" extensions="ExtensionCreatorController">
    <script>function setFocusOnLoad() {}</script>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Extension EX-{!Request__c.name} for request {!Request__c.name}"> 
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Input Section" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField id="inpMovein" value="{!Request__c.Moveindate__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField id="inpMoveout" value="{!Request__c.Moveoutdate__c}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Calculate Intermediate Steps" action="{!calculation}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Intermediate Calculations" columns="2">
                <apex:outputText value="{!result}" label="Rental days of extension"/> 
                <apex:outputText value="{!newTotalRentDuration}" label="New total rented days (incl ext.)"/>
                <apex:outputText value="{0,number,#,##0.00}" label="New Landlord Fee:">€   
                    <apex:param value="{!newLandlordFee}"/>
                </apex:outputText>
                <apex:outputText value="{0,number,#,##0.00}" label="New Net Landlord Fee:">€   
                    <apex:param value="{!newNetLandlordFee}"/>
                </apex:outputText>
                <apex:outputText value="{0,number,#,##0.00}" label="New Tenant Fee:">€   
                    <apex:param value="{!newTenantFee}"/>
                </apex:outputText>
                <apex:outputText value="{0,number,#,##0.00}" label="New Net Tenant Fee:">€   
                    <apex:param value="{!newNetTenantFee}"/>
                </apex:outputText> 
                <apex:outputText value="{!Request__c.Tenant_Fee_Type__c}" label="Tenant Fee Package:"/>
                <apex:outputText value="{!Request__c.Apartment_Country__c}" label="Tenant Fee Country:"/>               
                <apex:commandButton value="Create Extension" rerender="one" action="{!InsertClone}"/>              
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**TestClass:**

```
@isTest
private class ExtensionCreatorControllerTest {
    /* Test */
    @isTest static void test() {
        Request__c r = new Request__c(name='Tester');
        r.Opportunity__c = '0069E000007EdUp';
        r.Landlord__c = '0019E00000bXH5E';
        r.Billing_Address__c = 'a0d9E000003S12H';
        r.Moveindate__c = date.newinstance(2018, 2, 17);
        r.Moveoutdate__c = date.newinstance(2019, 2, 17);
        r.ServiceFeeLandlord__c = 200;
        r.TotalRent__c = 2000;
        r.MonthlyRent__c = 1000;

        insert r;
        Request__c ReqAfterInsert =  [SELECT Id, TotalRentalTime__c FROM Request__c WHERE Id = :r.Id];
        System.debug('TotalRentalTime is: ' + ReqAfterInsert.TotalRentalTime__c);

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(r);
        ExtensionCreatorController e = new ExtensionCreatorController(sc);
        System.debug('Moveindate__c is: ' + r.Moveindate__c);
        System.debug('Moveindate__c is: ' + r.Moveindate__c);
        System.debug('Moveoutdate__c is: ' + r.Moveoutdate__c);
        Integer test = r.Moveindate__c.daysBetween(r.Moveoutdate__c);
        System.debug('Theoretical RentalTime is: ' + test);
        System.debug('TotalRentalTime is: ' + r.TotalRentalTime__c);
        System.debug('ServiceFeeLandLord is: ' + r.ServiceFeeLandlord__c);
        System.debug('TotalRent is: ' + r.TotalRent__c);
        e.calculation();
        System.assertEquals(e.result, 366);   
    }       
}


    /* Calculate Intermediate Results   
    public void calculation() {
        result = requ.Moveindate__c.daysBetween(requ.Moveoutdate__c);
        newTotalRentDuration = result + requ.TotalRentalTime__c;
        initialCommission = requ.ServiceFeeLandlord__c/requ.TotalRent__c;

        if (newTotalRentDuration < 366) {
            totalMonths = totalMonths(requ.MoveIndate__c,requ.MoveOutdate__c);
        } else {
            totalMonths = math.ceil((365 - requ.TotalRentalTime__c)/30);
        }

        newLandlordFee = initialCommission * totalMonths * requ.MonthlyRent__c;

        if ((requ.Apartment_Country__c == 'Germany') || (requ.Apartment_Country__c == 'Deutschland')) {
            newNetLandlordFee = newLandlordFee/1.19; 
        } 
        else newNetLandlordFee = newLandlordFee;

        newTenantFee = calcTenantFee(totalMonths);
        if ((requ.Apartment_Country__c == 'Germany') || (requ.Apartment_Country__c == 'Deutschland')) {
            newNetTenantFee = newTenantFee/1.19; 
        } 
        else newNetTenantFee = newTenantFee;            
    } */
```

Comment: you could avoid the addFields by using apex:inputHidden on the VF page

Comment: Would help for the testing I guess :)

Comment: if it is formula fields you care about in the test method, you need to query all fields that are assumed by addFields for `r` before passing it to `ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(r)`. That is how you simulate the addFields (or apex:inputHidden) in a testmethod